# FTDI FT232RL on custom PCB works only when warm

Tags: pcb, usb, uart, ftdi

I've made a simple PCB to interface an RF transceiver with a PC. I can't say it's perfect, I completely disregarded impedances and similar stuff when designing it. However, it seems to work, but only when the FTDI chip is... warm. Literally, no matter what value of resistors and capacitors I put on the board, everything is fine if I heat up the FTDI chip before connecting to the PC. When I make a "cold start" (pun intended), Windows fails to read device descriptor. What is happening? Tested on multiple FTDI FT232RL chips - same thing happens. However, when I connect a off-the-shelf FTDI USB-UART dongle, everything works perfectly, so not a driver issue I guess.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How warm is warm and how cold is cold? If warm is actually hot, redo your solder joints. Show us a photo of the board.

Comment: The 3V3OUT bypass cap has wrong value. It should be 100nF.

Comment: @DKNguyen By warm i mean like 40-50 degrees Celsius, sometimes it's enough to warm it up using your finger, sometimes a hairdryer. Definitely not the solder-melting kind of warm. By cold I mean room temp.

Comment: That might be solder joints.

Comment: @DKNguyen I re-did them multiple times, even tested various FT232RL chips, and checked the joints under a microscope. I'll try redoing them once more, but is there any other reason why this might be happening?

Comment: @PineLel Not that I know of. I've never experienced the problem myself.

Comment: If the chip works when you push on it with your finger, then the soldering needs to be touched up.

Comment: It might be an issue with the reset pin, in the data sheet it says to either leave it floating or at VCC if not in use, but right now it's receiving 3.3V while VCC is 5V (maybe there is some undefined behavior happening). Table 5.11 suggest this won't be a problem, but check the voltage on the reset pin just to be safe. It also might be worth trying to lift the RESET pin to see if leaving it floating fixes the problem

Comment: It's also worth looking at section 6.2 of the datahsheet, it mentions that some 'USB hosts or hub controllers will power up erratically' if current is allowed to flow from RESET# to USBDP through an internal 1.5k resistor (which it will if power is provided through JP1 pin 3 before attaching the USB)

Comment: @Smith Pushing it makes no difference, only heat does. Changed bypass cap to 100nF, no difference. Redid solder joints, no difference. Removed the RESET pin (trace cut), no difference. Board is powered only via USB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to connect the `TEST` pin to GND.

[image]

It's always a good start to compare your schematics to the configuration specified by the datasheet.

[image]

Source: [Datasheet](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/DS_FT232R.pdf)

---

Also, the USB ID pin has to be left unconnected (or pulled high) to enable the USB *DEVICE* role.

Comment: I cut the RESET trace and bridged TEST to AGND, no success either :(

Comment: For time being (until we know more), remove C3 and C4, and replace C1 with 100nF. Also, add 4.7uF in parallel to C14.
And maybe it's just your layouting software, but I can't see any GND connections. I would at least expect to see traces to the vias.

Comment: Replaced C1 with 100nF, no success. In the morning (it's midnight here) I'll try removing C3 and C4 as well as adding 4.7uF to C14. As for the ground connections, the screenshot, for readibility, is without GND polygon visible.

Comment: I thought as much. Just make sure that you haven't missed any of the 4 GNDs. Also, check that VCCIO is jumpered to VCC (JP1: 2-3).

Comment: VCCIO is currently hard-soldered to VCC on JP1 to avoid any jumper-related issues. Will check the solder connections once more tomorrow under a microscope

Comment: And now that I think about it: shouldn't the ID pin be left unconnected for USB devices (DEVICE role)? I'm a bit tired right now, it's 1 in the morning....

Comment: Removing R4, bridging TEST to AGND and correcting DP/DM resistors (had 47Ohm soldered instead of 27Ohm, changed to 10Ohm) did the job. Thanks!

Comment: Good to see you managed to fix the problem. Now that we know which of the modifications fixed the issue, I'll update my answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to pull downs and pullups (always check and use them, don't let the device configure itself in a state you won't know) Make sure you also check the soldering on the chip. Thermal expansion can make intermittent connections change over temperature. For example in the picture below pins that are not fully soldered can make or break connection over temperature.

[image]
Source: https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2021/06/18/13-common-pcb-soldering-problems-to-avoid/